# Decimal precision and scale

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, decimal

This expression uses implicit conversion:

```
SELECT 9.999 * '9.999'
```

and evaluates 99.980001.

If I log the type information using this:

```
SELECT
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(9.999 * '9.999', 'BaseType'),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(9.999 * '9.999', 'Precision'),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(9.999 * '9.999', 'Scale'),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(9.999 * '9.999', 'MaxLength')
```

I get:

- BaseType **numeric**
- *Precision **9***
- Scale **6**
- MaxLength **5**

I believe I understand all the results except the precision.
If number of the digits left to the decimal point is 2 and right is 6, this totals 8.

Why does SQL Server calculate 9 here?

P.S. I use SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Precision, Scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx)

Looking at the section

```
Operation:
e1 * e2
```

you will find

```
Result precision
p1 + p2 + 1
```

So in your case `4+4+1 => 9`

Further to that, you will notice that

```
SELECT  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(99.999 * '9.999', 'Precision'), --11 => p1+p1+1
        SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(99.999 * '99.999', 'Precision'), --11 => p1+p1+1
        SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(99.999 * 9.999, 'Precision'), --10 => p1+p2+1
        SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(99.999 * 99.999, 'Precision') -- 11 => p1+p2+1
```

whereas

```
SELECT  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(9.999 * '9.999', 'Precision') --9 => p1+p1+1
```

and

```
SELECT  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(9.99 * '9.999', 'Precision')
```

cuases

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have RTFM myself, thanks! Now I have to find out why does this precision increment happen at all.